# PouchDB Authentication library in Angular2 Cli project

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular, pouchdb, systemjs

I am having trouble importing the PouchDB Authentication library (https://github.com/nolanlawson/pouchdb-authentication) into my Angular2 Cli Typescript project.

I have added this to my typings:

```
declare module "pouchdb-authentication" {}
```

My `system-config.ts` file contains in `map`:

```
'pouchdb-authentication': 'vendor/pouchdb-authentication/dist/',
```

and in `packages`:

```
"pouchdb-authentication": {
  main: "pouchdb.authentication.js",
  defaultExtension: "js"
},
```

I am attempting to use it like so:

```
PouchDB.plugin(require('pouchdb-authentication'));
```

I have also tried:

```
import * as PouchDBAuthentication from 'pouchdb-authentication';
```

Currently, I am getting this error in my console:

> zone.js:461: Unhandled Promise rejection: (SystemJS) TypeError: AMD module http://localhost:4200/vendor/pouchdb-authentication/dist/pouchdb.authentication.js did not define

Any ideas would be much appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure you want to pull in `dist/pouchdb.authentication.js` as opposed to using the CommonJS package? `dist/` contains the UMD package, in which case it looks like SystemJS is trying to load it as AMD.

**Edit**: nevermind, I see I forgot to build it as UMD. I'll fix that and then you should be able to use the `dist/` just fine (although again, I don't think you need to since SystemJS should be able to consume CommonJS just fine).

Opened an issue here: https://github.com/nolanlawson/pouchdb-authentication/issues/103

**Edit**: fixed in pouchdb-authentication 0.5.2, please try again